# React JS coponent not rendering using map function

Tags: reactjs

I hava a component called videoRow i try to render this component using dummy values now i get data from a useEffect Hook i have to use that data to render my component but when i try to do so it dont show anything. I even try console log to check weather i get my data or not it print my data on console means my useEffect is working But when i try this data on my videoRow component it not show anything

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../css/searchPage.css";
import TuneSharpIcon from "@mui/icons-material/TuneSharp";
import ChannelRow from "./ChannelRow";
import VideoRow from "./VideoRow";
import { selectInput } from "../features/inputSlice";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Axios from "axios";

function SearchPage() {
  const getQuery = useSelector(selectInput);
  const API_URL = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=4&key=APIKEY&type=video&q=${getQuery.input}`;
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      let request = await Axios.get(API_URL);
      setData(request);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [API_URL]);

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div className="searchPage">
      <div className="filter">
        <TuneSharpIcon></TuneSharpIcon>
        <h2>FILTERS</h2>
      </div>
      <hr></hr>
      <ChannelRow
        image="https://images.indianexpress.com/2022/01/Republic-Day_1200_AP2022.jpg"
        channelName="Dummy"
        verified
        subs="670k"
        noOfVideos={567}
        desc="You can find awesome programming lessons here! Also, expect programming tips and tricks that will take your coding skills to the ..."
      ></ChannelRow>
      <hr></hr>

      {data?.data?.items?.forEach((item) => {
        console.log(item.snippet.title);
        console.log(item?.snippet.thumbnails.high.url)
        console.log(item?.snippet.publishedAt)
        console.log(item?.snippet.description)
        console.log(item?.snippet.channelTitle)
        return(<VideoRow
          image={item?.snippet.thumbnails.high.url}
          channelName={item?.channelTitle}
          timestamp={item?.snippet.publishedAt}
          title={item?.snippet.title}
          desc={item?.snippet.description}
          views="1.4M"
          subs="1.4M"
        ></VideoRow>)
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `data?.data?.items?.forEach` to `data?.data?.items?.map`. `forEach` returns nothing. So, even if you return the component from the callback, `forEach` will just ignore it. But, `map` will return all transformed results as an array.

You can read more about [lists in react here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).